# How to select element by data area

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have this HTML form:

[image: click here to see the image]

I'm writing a bot that he can go to the specific website and navigate to a certain page the image above where my bot confused. I need to select the first div data-area:"reslut1" and click on it to navigate to the next page
i'm using javascript with puppetteer chromuim
if anyone can help?
thank you

[image: I tried to do this]

Comment: Can you please add the code snippets of what you've tried so far?

Comment: which language, library or  framework you use for the scraping of data?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: i edit the question above

Comment: I'm using puppeteer to scrap data

Comment: Shouldn't `'.result1'` be `[data-area]='result1'` it looks like you are trying to fetch by class, but the element does not have that class.

Comment: the idea is how to select the div I try with selector didn't work because the div change

Comment: data-area didn't change every time the bot  navigate

Comment: @RaulSauco should be `'[data-area="result1"]'` but yes you are correct.

Comment: @Reyno you are right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using the **wrong selector**, you are trying to find the element by class:

```
.result1
```

While you should be trying to select by `data-area`:

```
[data-area="result1"]
```

To perform a click on that element, you can use:

```js
await page.click('div[data-area="result1"]');
```

Comment: one more thing how can the bot click on the div to continue

Comment: `await page.click('div[data-area="result1"]');` Should perform the click on that element.